# Unable to perform perfect search using IF statement

Tags: c, comparison

I am writing code through C programming and using visual studio to compile the program.

here i am trying to find the number from manually input array elements but it is not working properly.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3
main()
{
int i=0;
int search_no=0;
int myArray[SIZE];

for(i=0;i<SIZE; i++)
{
    printf("Enter value : ");
    scanf("%d", &myArray[i]);
}

printf("Enter value to search : ");
scanf("%d", &search_no);
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
{
    if(search_no==myArray[i])
    {
        printf("Number found\n");
    break;
    }
if(search_no!=myArray[i])
    {
        printf("Unable to find. Kindly re-check the number\n");
        break;
    }
}


getch();

}
```

It gets compile but it is not searching the element correctly and if i remove the Last IF statement then it works perfectly. I want to print the message in both ways if value found or not.

Thanks.

Comment: You never check more than one element of the array. If the first element you check matches, you print a success message and stop. If the first element you check doesn't match, you print a failure message and stop. You only want to fail when *nothing* matches, not when *something* doesn't match.

Comment: So how i should correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is, if first value in the array is not the one you are looking for, you get out of the loop.

Put the not found code after the loop.

```
int found = 0;
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
{
    if(search_no==myArray[i])
    {
        printf("Number found\n");
        found = 1;
        break;
    }        
}

if(found == 0)
{
    printf("Unable to find. Kindly re-check the number\n");
}
```

Comment: Why here is so different? because when i write the same code into C#, i never come to know such problems and C# code works exactly as i expect. I just want to know the logic of adding one more variable to verify the condition. Why this job is not solely done by the defined If Block?

Comment: I highly doubt that the same loop here translated to C# does find the value if it is not the first one. Here's a C# of your loop, it doesn't work in C# either. https://ideone.com/orVzIw

Comment: and if i am using IF ELSE block to verify condition why is it not working?

Comment: Still the same, it will exit early since it will go in the else block if first value is not the right one.

Comment: Thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk you :)
I have got the your attention :D